# material-ui Button color won't change through css styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, components

i just learned the basics of react and react-ui and when i tried to change the color of a material-ui Button, it doesn't work unless i use inline styling :

**the button component :**

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

function MyButton() {
  return (
    <Button
      // style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      className="signUp"
    >
      Sign Up
    </Button>
  );
}
export default MyButton;
```

**css styling :**

```
.signUp{
    background-color : black;
    color : yellow;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 8px 8px white);
    float:right;
    }
```

**inline style :**

```
style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}
```

*so what do you think the problem is?*

Comment: You need to import the CSS into your button component or use one of MUI's styling methods (e.g. withStyles, makeStyles)

Comment: i will try that, i thought that material-ui components function like other components i create, which means that they would accept className, if that's not the case can you please tell me the difference? thanks

Comment: Yes, they accept `className`, however how does className know what class you are referring to if you haven't imported it into the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your CSS stylesheet in your `MyButton` JSX file.

For example, if you store your button CSS styling in a file called `styles.css` and this file is in the same directory of your `MyButton` JSX file, add the following line:

```
import "./styles.css";
```

So the entire code becomes:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import "./styles.css"; // Add this line!

function MyButton() {
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className="signUp">
      Sign Up
    </Button>
  );
}
export default MyButton;
```

[image: Edit on CodeSandbox]